# Equivalence relation for a group.

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations

let $H,K \subseteq G$ all be groups. A relation ~ on $G$ is defined by x ~ y $\iff x = hyk$ for some $h\in H$ and $k\in K$. I'm to prove that ~ is an equivalence relation on $G$.

I was just wondering if when I'm to prove reflexivity if this holds:

x~x:

$x = hxk$

$h^{-1}xk^{-1} = h^{-1}hxkk^{-1} = x
$
, since $h^{-1} \in H$ and $k^{-1} \in K$ and so it's proven?

Ie it doesn't have to be the same element of $H$ and the same element of $K$ right?

Comment: For $x$ equivalent to $x$ I would choose the neural elements.

Comment: To add on to @Wuestenfux  Note that $G\cap H \cap K = e$ where $e$ is the identity element of G.  So, for every element in $x \in G$, we have $exe = x$.  Hence, since $e \in H$ and $e\in K$, $x\sim x$ for all $x \in G$.

Comment: Yeah, you're both completely correct. I can't believe I didn't consider $\{e\}$ =/